# Billing has not been enabled for this project

Tags: google-bigquery

I enabled free trial last night but I'm still unable to create a data set to save a query into a table. Anyone know why?

Comment: The project is optimal-sun-108515

Comment: Enable billing and you are good to go.

Comment: How do I do that? In https://console.developers.google.com/project, the Charges column shows $0.00 for that project.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, trial was enabled but I couldn't add dataset in BigQuery. The solution for me was to go to any storage service like BigTable and click Enable Billing there.

Comment: This was the issue for me - seems like BigQuery requires the BigTable APIs to be enabled so while I didn't enable billing there, navigating to BigTable prompted the message of 'Enabling BigTable APIs' at the bottom of the screen. Once done, I could go back into BigQuery and execute queries.

Answer (score 1):

Enable billing and you are good to go:

https://console.developers.google.com/billing

Comment: having the same problem, everything is enabled and still getting this error message...

Comment: I would also like to add this [step-by-step guide](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653?hl=en) on how to create a new billing account which will then allow you to 'Submit and enable billing'

Answer (score 1):

I received the 'enable billing' even though billing was enabled. In my case I needed to enable the BigQuery API. I'm not sure why the error message didn't specify this directly, it seems as though it should have.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to create a new project or copy my old project into a new one ***after*** signing up for the free trial. I think the free trial only applies to projects you created after you sign up.

When it gave me the error you are experiencing, the first sentence was "Billing has not been enabled for ***this project***."

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a [valid billing account setup](https://console.developers.google.com/billing), you need to also ensure your project that has the BigQuery access also is connected to that billing account.

For me the problem was solved by going to [Billing > Projects](https://console.developers.google.com/billing/projects) and then selecting a newly created organization, under which the project I was trying to get BigQuery working for was, and then I needed to attach the project to that account.

So be sure to check the tab "My projects" in the Billing section, and also the dropdown menu inside that tab called "Select an organization". When you find the right project, click the "Actions" button (i.e. the three dots) and select "Change billing account" and "Set account".